# Dynamic Captions for Access Web App

Tags: ms-access-web-app

Wondering if it is possible to change the caption of a view on an Access 2013 Web App on SharePoint dynamically? I can't seem to find anything on Google that indicates it is. I have tried using `=[Controls].[ControlName]`, etc. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems we could use [SetProperty Macro Action (Access custom web app)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj248976.aspx) with setting Control Name blank to set the Caption property for the view.